# `manage.py inspectdb` tells me that I don't have an ENGINE specified in my default database, but the docs say that default can be blank

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I'm creating a django web app that is going to be a database management portal for multiple databases. Because the web app will touch multiple databases, it doesn't make sense to have a default. However, when I run `manage.py inspectdb` I get an error saying that the `ENGINE` value isn't set on my database. It most definitely is.

Here's my `DATABASES` setting in `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    },
    'my_db': {
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': '192.168.0.255',
        'PORT': '',
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

If I run `manage.py inspectdb` using this setup I get this error:

`settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.`

This doesn't make sense to me, since it says in the documentation that 'default' can be a blank {}.

However, if I supply a dummy NAME and ENGINE variable to the default db, it seems to work fine for the default DB, but it ignores `my_db`.

If I set `default` to look at `my_db`'s information I get a login error (so I know at least something is working right there, even if my creds are bad).

So, **what am I getting wrong in my database setup here?**

Comment: From the docs

**Django requires that a default database entry be defined, but the parameters dictionary can be left blank if it will not be used.** To do this, you must set up DATABASE_ROUTERS for all of your apps’ models, including those in any contrib and third-party apps you’re using, so that no queries are routed to the default database. The following is an example settings.py snippet defining two non-default databases, with the default entry intentionally left empty:

Comment: To be clear, I have a DATABASE_ROUTERS setting as well.

Comment: You may try this `python manage.py inspectdb --database my_db`

Comment: That definitely does it, thanks. I think what I'll end up doing is just throw in dummy variables into the default. Many thanks, my man. If you want to put that into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a database for which you need to `inspectdb`

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database your_db_name
```

For more details see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb)